# Routing in Windows XP with IP restriction

Tags: windows-xp, routing, security

I have WinXP with two connections (e.g. `A` and `B`).

What is the easiest way to make WinXP act as gateway to `B` for one and only one given computer (IP) from `A`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to just assign static IPs on both ends (A & B) with a very restrictive subnet mask (e.g. 192.168.1.1 & 192.168.1.2 with a net mask of 255.255.255.252).

Comment: But I need to comunicate with other computers in the network...

Comment: You did not elaborate that there are additional systems on the second connection. The same approach can be used to add a route on the forwarding system between the two networks (if the systems is setup to forward packets between its interfaces - e.g. route).